# HTML5 audio tag promise error after user play in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, safari, html5-audio

I have audio tag with src from amazon and when I click play in Safari, the promise fails with an error: "NotAllowedError (DOM Exception 35): The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission."

It works if I set src to some mp3 file located on my server. Does anybody know what this is happening?

```js
var audio = document.createElement('audio');
audio.src = "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/hitzmania/Xin8nXIPz4YH";

document.getElementById('play').addEventListener('click', function() {

  var promise = audio.play();
  if (promise !== undefined) {
    promise.then(_ => {}).catch(error => {
      alert(error)
    });
  }
  return false;
})
```

```html
<a href="#" id="play">play</a>
```

Comment: What's the error ?